# How can I create a comic-strip style speech bubble?

Tags: css

How can I style a `div` to look like a comic-strip speech bubble in CSS?

Here's an image demonstrating what I mean:

[image]

Is there a way of doing this in pure CSS?

Comment: Speech balloon, I believe is the word you're looking for. Check this out: http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/

Answer (score 3):

A quick example, you can tweak it to fit your needs .. and since I cannot post a fiddle without code:

HTML:

```
<div class="balloon">
    O hai !
    <span class="tip"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body { background: #000; }
.balloon {
    width: 250px;
    height: 75px;
    padding: 50px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 34px;
    text-align: center;
}
.balloon .tip {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 70px;
    bottom: -20px;
    border: solid 10px;
    border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6rzDK/